# RESTRICCIÓN DE CLAVE FORÁNEA EN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema al definir una restricción de clave foránea para esta tabla en phpMyAdmin:

### Tabla Grupos (contiene la clave foránea "profesor")

[image: Estructura de la tabla "grupos"]

### Tabla Profesores (a la que hace referencia la clave foránea)

[image: Estructura de la tabla "profesores"]

#### Definición de grupos

```sql
CREATE TABLE `grupos` (
 CREATE TABLE `grupos` (
  `id_grupo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grado` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6') NOT NULL,
  `nombre` enum('A','B','C') NOT NULL,
  `profesor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_alumnos` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_grupo`),
  KEY `fk_grupos_profesor` (`profesor`),
  CONSTRAINT `grupos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`profesor`) REFERENCES `profesores` (`id_prof`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

#### Definición de profesores

```sql
CREATE TABLE `profesores` (
  `id_prof` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_p` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_m` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clave_sp` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_prof`),
  UNIQUE KEY `clave` (`clave_sp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Cuando trato de añadir las restricciones ON DELETE y ON UPDATE desde la interfaz gráfica me sale esto:

[image: Error al añadir restricción de clave]

Y si lo hago mediante código  me sale esto:

**Consulta:**

```sql
ALTER TABLE grupos DROP CONSTRAINT `grupos_ibfk_1`; ALTER TABLE grupos
ADD CONSTRAINT `grupos_ibfk_1`FOREIGN KEY (profesor)
REFERENCES profesores (id_prof) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**Resultado:**

Error
consulta SQL: Copiar

ALTER TABLE grupos DROP CONSTRAINT `grupos_ibfk_1`;
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1091 - No puedo eliminar (DROP CONSTRAINT) `grupos_ibfk_1`. compuebe que el campo/clave existe

Answer (score 3):

Primeramente, hay error de sintaxis en el `CREATE TABLE` de **`grupos`**, repites dos veces la sentencia inicial.

En segundo lugar, esto no es posible:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT `grupos_ibfk_1`FOREIGN KEY (profesor)
REFERENCES profesores (id_prof) 
ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

En el `ON DELETE` le estás diciendo que haga algo contradictorio con la definición de la columna. Observa que la columna es definida así:

```
`profesor` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

Si la columna no admite nulos, no le puedes decir que asigne un valor nulo en el caso de `ON DELETE`, para que esto sea posible, debes quitar el `NOT NULL` en la definición de la columna.

Otra posibilidad es definir otro tipo de acción para el `ON DELETE`, acorde con la definición de la columna, por ejemplo, `CASCADE`, pero eso ya depende de lo que necesites.

En principio, para que funcione con la definición que estás intentando, sería así:

```
CREATE TABLE `profesores` (
  `id_prof` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_p` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_m` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clave_sp` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_prof`),
  UNIQUE KEY `clave` (`clave_sp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `grupos` (
  `id_grupo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grado` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6') NOT NULL,
  `nombre` enum('A','B','C') NOT NULL,
  `profesor` int(11), -- NOT NULL,
  `total_alumnos` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_grupo`),
  KEY `fk_grupos_profesor` (`profesor`),
  CONSTRAINT `grupos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`profesor`) REFERENCES `profesores` (`id_prof`) 
  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TxwVGW__)